# Confusing concentration calculation about vivianite solubility

Tags: solubility

I'm confused about the results of [PO4] and [Fe(II)] calculated in [a paper](https://aslopubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.4319/lo.2003.48.2.0929). The example they posted is shown in the figure below:

[image: Fig_example]

I tried to calculate the phosphate and Fe(II) concentration. The calculation process is below:

$\ce{ Fe3(PO4)2 8H2O <=> 3Fe^2+ + 2PO4^3- + 8H2O}$

Let's set the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ as 3x mol/L, concentration of $\ce{PO4^3-}$ as 2x mol/L, then:

(3x)^3*(2x)^2 = 10^-36,   which makes x = 2.47$*$10^-8

So concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ is 3x = 7.42$*$10^-8 mol/L, concentration of $\ce{PO4^3-}$ is 2x = 4.95$*$10^-8 mol/L.

However, the paper said that Fe(II) and P concentration is 1.53$*$10^-5 mol/L and 1.02$*$10^-5 mol/L, respectively.

Here are my two questions:

(1) Why my calculation is not the same (even in the magnitude) as the paper's results?

(2) Why do they mention "pH = 7", I couldn't find where is this "pH" take part in the solubiity calcculation.

Comment: At pH 7, most of phosphate is in form of HPO3^2- and H2PO4-, with traces of PO4^3-. Therefore real solubility is much higher, compared to the simple  calculation, not considering other phosphate forms.